# Combining values from one column by the key value from another column

Tags: sql

I need to combine all values by one column depends on the key from another column. Can someone help me to get out of this problem please?

here is the short example of my problem.

```
CUST_ID      CUST_REL_ID
100          1
100          2
100          3
100          4
200          5
200          6
200          7

CUST_ID      CUST_REL_ID
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            4
2            1
2            2
2            3
2            4
...
5            5
5            6
5            7
```

Comment: Is that first sample table data, and then the expected result? Looks like a self JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh yes, first one is the sample data and the second one has to be the result.

Comment: What is the logic that turns `cust_id = 100` into `cust_id = 1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name CUST_ID column in the first table is the main key, so it means all values from the second column replace the keys which belongs to the first key and comined in the second column by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a self-join:

```
select t1.cust_rel_id, t2.cust_rel_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
order by t1.cust_rel_id, t2.cust_rel_id;
```

I don't understand your naming conventions.  The column called `cust_id` in the result set looks nothing like the column called `cust_id` in the source data.  But this appears to be what you want to do.